Error Writing to a Delta Lake via Python in Azure
I am getting the following error when trying to write file to Delta lake:-

Generic DeltaTable error: Invalid schema write mode provided: append,
only these are supported: ['overwrite', 'merge']

Here is the python function I have:-
def write_delta(df, tableName, writemode):
    uri = f'az://bronze/delta/delta-operations/{tableName}'
    
    write_deltalake(
        uri,
        df,
        schema_mode= writemode,
        storage_options= storage_options
    )
    return


The error message says you can only choose "overwrite" or "merge" for your write mode. What is your writemode variable set to?

it is not set. I would directly state 'append' when I call the function.

That's the issue though: "append" is not valid, per the error message.

Error clearly states that only overwrite and merge should be given in writemode.
I append data to delta lake using using spark by using below code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession as cho
from delta.tables import DeltaTable as rith

ri_ch = cho.builder \
    .appName("DeltaLakeExample") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem") \
    .config("fs.azure.account.key.accname.dfs.core.windows.net", "p0L9It3tJCFApw==") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtensions") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()

rith_data = ri_ch.createDataFrame([(6, "Cho")], schema=["id", "name"])
ri_path = "abfss://cont-name@accname.dfs.core.windows.net/tablename"
rith_data.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(ri_path)
delta_table = rith.forPath(ri_ch, ri_path)
ri_ch.read.format("delta").load(ri_path).show()

Output:
id name
8 Rithwik
6 cho
2 Bojja


No need to post an answer. Also no need to provide code different from the OP. This is just about using the wrong write mode, as mentioned in the comments.
